# How do I get the value of a variable from another method without passing it off as an argument?

Tags: java, variables, inheritance

I'm trying to create a chatting application (yes I know, not very creative) and I want to transfer the socket variable's value into the other method.

But I'm too confused as to what should I do?

I've already tried passing it off as an argument which for some reason doesn't work, also tried to declare the variables outside of the method which also doesn't work.

```
    public void DeclaringVariables() throws IOException{

        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.255"); 
        int port = 1201; 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter your name: "); 
        name = sc.nextLine(); 
        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(port); 

        // Since we are deploying 
        socket.setTimeToLive(0); 
        //this on localhost only (For a subnet set it as 1) 

        socket.joinGroup(group); 
        Thread t = new Thread(new
        ReadThread(socket,group,port)); 

            // Spawn a thread for reading messages 
        t.start();

    }          

/**
 *
 */
public void SendButton() {

    try {

        while(true) {

                String message; 
                message = sc.nextLine(); 
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase(GroupChat.TERMINATE)) 
                { 
                    finished = true; 
                    socket.leaveGroup(group); 
                    socket.close(); 
                    break; 
                } 
                message = name + ": " + message; 
                byte[] buffer = message.getBytes(); 
                DatagramPacket datagram = new
                DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,group,port); 
                socket.send(datagram); 

    }
    } 

    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChatGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

Comment: @Spara - statics should be avoided unless there is a good reason (constants, singletons (sparingly), etc.) - to access anything within the same class it's enough to have an instance variable, not static.

Comment: `I've already tried passing it off as an argument which for some reason doesn't work` it should work. Please post the code.

Comment: Can you please show the full class you are writing? Also, method names in Java should be written in lowerCamelCase, i.e. `declaringVariables()` and `sendButton()`

Comment: @Spara it is not, it's a local variable

Comment: @Spara it shouldn't be. It's supposed to be one per instance, not one per JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need `socket` in more than one method, consider declaring it as a class attribute, instead of a local variable. In that way you can instantiate it in the class constructor and access it through all the methods in the class. Like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    // declare it here
    private MulticastSocket socket;

    public MyClass() {
        // instantiate it here
        socket = new MulticastSocket(1201); 
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        // now you can use it everywhere!
        socket.someMethod();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I do that? All that you just said just went over my head lol

Comment: @PaperTronics I updated my answer. Please read a Java tutorial, this is literally the first thing they teach you about OO programming ;)